# How can I code if I want to limit the number of the records nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 Models.

- Community
- CommunityTopic

**Community** has_many **CommunityTopics**

But what if I want to limit the number of **CommunityTopics** that are owned by one Community?
I'd like to limit it up to 1000 records which can be owned by one Community.

How can I code that in my controller's new action with flash error message?
and what should I code in models/community_topics.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a validation in your `CommunityTopic` model, it could be named `check_limits`

```
def check_limits
  if self.community.communitytopics.count == 1000
    self.errors.add("can't create more topics for this community")
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

I would recommend using a constant instead of just writing 1000, in case you need to change it later.